# Starting two windows services in the same application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, service

I have the following issue.

I have two windows services application to start in the same application (WPF), both were already installed. but when I have to "Start" them (ServiceController.Start()), only the service which starts first keeps turned on, the other returns the message:

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control
>   request in a timely fashion

This is my code to start them:

```
//*TS_TimeOut timespan has 1 hour
    private void InitServiceOne()
    {
        ServiceController SControllerServiceOne = new ServiceController("ServiceOne", Environment.MachineName);

        SControllerServiceOne.Start();
        SControllerServiceOne.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, TS_TimeOut);
    }

    private void InitServiceTwo()
    {

        ServiceController SControllerServiceTwo = new ServiceController("ServiceTwo", Environment.MachineName);

        SControllerServiceTwo.Start();
        SControllerServiceTwo.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, TS_TimeOut);
    }
```

This is the code that I've used to install them:

```
    private void InstallServiceOne(string strServiceOnePath)
    {
        ServiceProcessInstaller ProcessServiceServiceOne = new ServiceProcessInstaller();

        ServiceInstaller ServiceInstallerOne = new ServiceInstaller();
        InstallContext Context = new System.Configuration.Install.InstallContext();
        String path = String.Format("/assemblypath={0}", strServiceOnePath));
        String[] cmdline = { path };

        Context = new System.Configuration.Install.InstallContext("", cmdline);
        ServiceInstallerOne.Context = Context;
        ServiceInstallerOne.DisplayName = "ServiceOne";
        ServiceInstallerOne.Description = "ServiceOne";
        ServiceInstallerOne.ServiceName = "ServiceOne";
        ServiceInstallerOne.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        ServiceInstallerOne.Parent = ProcessServiceServiceOne;

        System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary stateServiceOne = new System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary();
        ServiceInstallerObjIntegracao.Install(stateServiceOne);
    }

    private void InstallServiceTwo(string strServiceTwoPath)
    {

        ServiceProcessInstaller ProcessServiceServiceTwo new ServiceProcessInstaller();

        ServiceInstaller ServiceInstallerTwo = new ServiceInstaller();
        InstallContext Context = new System.Configuration.Install.InstallContext();
        String path = String.Format("/assemblypath={0}", strServiceTwoPath);
        String[] cmdline = { path };

        Context = new System.Configuration.Install.InstallContext("", cmdline);
        ServiceInstallerTwo.Context = Context;
        ServiceInstallerTwo.DisplayName = "ServiceTwo";
        ServiceInstallerTwo.Description = "ServiceTwo";
        ServiceInstallerTwo.ServiceName = "ServiceTwo";
        ServiceInstallerTwo.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        ServiceInstallerTwo.Parent = ProcessServiceServiceTwo;

        System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary stateServiceTwo = new System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary();
        ServiceInstallerObjBRMonitoring.Install(stateServiceTwo);

    }
```

It's my first question in the stackoverflow community and english is not my mother tongue. 
My apologies if I commited any mistake.

Comment: Have you looked in the event viewer for any exception details?

Comment: I want to confirm, If you run `InitServiceTwo` before you run `InitServiceOne` does service "two" work and services "one" times out?

Comment: yes, if I run InitServiceTwo before InitServiceOne , ServiceTwo works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem have been solved!

I just had to change from Debug to Release and Install the Release .exe, now both services are running and working without any problem.